# Error 1136 in Mysql for syntax in my database

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table doc_list (
    Serial_no int auto_increment,
    First_name varchar (50),
    last_name varchar (50),
    speciality varchar (50),
    address varchar (100),
    area varchar (50),
    phone_no int (15),
    email varchar(100),
    primary key(serial_no)
);

insert into doc_list (Serial_no, First_name, last_name, speciality, address, area, phone_no)
    values ("Abha", "gupta", "Gynaecology", "B-16 Mathur Vaishya Nagar Tonk Road", "Pratap Nagar", 9829133773);
```

I'm getting this error message:
**Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**
I dont want to input anything in this email section in this column, so what should i do?

Comment: Please don't add tags for DBMS products that don't apply to your question.

Comment: If you share data here, make sure you anonimize it. In this particular case it's probably not a big deal, but it's better to get used to it *before* you share clients details.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
insert into 
doc_list 
(First_name, last_name, speciality, address, area, phone_no) 
values 
("Abha", "gupta", "Gynaecology", "B-16 Mathur Vaishya Nagar Tonk Road", "Pratap Nagar", 9829133773);
```

You must not include auto incremented column in the insert statement.

Comment: Not strictly true,you can provide a value to an auto_increment column if you wish to override auto_increment - but I wouldn't advise it as a matter of course.

Comment: Agree with you. We can indeed bypass auto_increment column by explicitly specifying a value.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed `Serial_no` in your query

```
insert into doc_list (Serial_no, First_name, last_name, speciality, address, area, phone_no)
    values ("Abha", "gupta", "Gynaecology", "B-16 Mathur Vaishya Nagar Tonk Road", "Pratap Nagar", 9829133773);
```

so write its value in query so your query work

Comment: Probably best not to since it is an auto_increment column.

Comment: If it's removed from the insert list then problem goes away and given the op's rep I suspect this is the way to go.

Comment: i say general not about this question